# How to get the binding value in code behind for phone call Task?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.

I need to apply phone call task.

**My XAML code**

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="spphone" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock x:Name="callnumber" Foreground="Red" Tap="phonenumber_Tap">
               <Run Text="{Binding phone}"/>
      </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

**CS Code**

```
   private void phonenumber_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
        call.PhoneNumber = "3333-525656";  /*I give static value for test*/
        call.Show();
     }
```

**Above code output**:-

[image]

**My problem**

In the above code i use static value like "3333-525656".

but i need to add value for call.PhoneNumber dynamically from the

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="callnumber" Foreground="Red" Tap="phonenumber_Tap">
        <Run Text="{Binding phone}"/>
 </TextBlock>
```

If i use  like below it's not work .

```
 call.PhoneNumber = callnumber.Text;
```

I need to get the phone value to call.phoneNumber

The phone value is bind from web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void phonenumber_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
        call.PhoneNumber = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
        call.Show();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)        
{
    PhoneNumberResult obj;
    obj.DisplayName = "testing name";
    obj.PhoneNumber = num.Text;
    PhoneCallTask call = new PhoneCallTask();
    call.DisplayName = obj.DisplayName;
    call.PhoneNumber = obj.PhoneNumber;
    call.Show();
}
```